# Baked texture is distorted

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I have a 3D scanned model that I want to bake to another mesh.
But this is the result in this specific area.
UVs are not distorted.
[image]Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Hello could you please pack the images and share the hi-res and the lo-res?

Comment: I trangulated the mesh and it somehow fixed the issue!